# Sequelize/Postgres model value/table column not recognized

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an app using Sequelize, Express, and a Postgres database. In it, I have a Sequelize model which has the fields `id`, `text`, `userId`, `user` `createdAt`, and have attempted to add another field `posttitle`. After creating the migration for the change and migrating, all fields including the one added through a migration show up in the table in psql.

Original migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Cheeps', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Cheeps');
  }
};
```

Migration to add model field:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Cheeps',
        'posttitle',
        {type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
      ),
    ]);
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

However, when I use .findAll() to list all instances of the model, only the original model fields (not including `posttitle`) can be retrieved. I also can't write to `posttitle` using .create().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `posttitle` to the model definition? Can you show the model definition?